# Booting via iPXE in EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, ipxe

Is it possible to implement iPXE on an EC2 instance so that it boots from an image stored in S3 (preferably) or from an image stored on another EC2 instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. iPXE and the more general class of PVS mechanisms require low-level (often Hypervisor) level access to the server in order to 'squirt' a boot image to the VM. This is not available in EC2, and in fact I'm not sure any public cloud service would allow it since a rogue operation at that level could compromise everything on the host.

Comment: I agree the hypervisor would need to have a virtual PXE client which grabs the image and boots it (and most clouds wouldn't allow the non-IP network traffic that I think PXE requires), but why would that make the host vulnerable in any way?

Comment: iPXE is working on AWS EC2 HVM instances as described @patlachance, however, it seems there is an issue with the netblock driver in the kernel since once the kernel is loaded the userland has no network connectivity. :(

Answer (score 5):

There is indeed no support in iPXE for AWS EC2 PV instances but iPXE can be use with AWS EC2 HVM instances.

For more information: http://forum.ipxe.org/showthread.php?tid=7913